# Bounds for Möbius function on finite posets.

Tags: combinatorics, order-theory

Given a finite poset $\mathbb{P}$ define $\varphi(\mathbb{P})$ to be the maximum value the Möbius function takes on an interval of $\mathbb{P}$. Given a natural number $n$ define $\varphi(n)$ to be the maximum value $\varphi(\mathbb{P})$ takes over all posets $\mathbb{P}$ of cardinality $n$.

I must show that $\varphi(n)>n^2$ and $\varphi(n) < n^n$ for sufficiently large $n$.

By Möbius function I mean the element of the incidence algebra given by $$\mu(x,y)=-\sum_{x\leq z < y} \mu(x,z)$$
which is the inverse of the $\zeta$ function.

I've been trying to construct examples of posets $\mathbb{P}$ such that I can find an interval where $\mu$ is bigger than $|\mathbb{P}|^2$ but have had no luck, the best I've done is construct a poset such that $\mu(\min,\max)$ is $|\mathbb{P}|-1$ ($1$ minimum $1$ maximum and $|\mathbb{P}|-2$ intermediate pairwise incompatible points). On the other hand I have no idea how to tackle $\varphi(n) < n^n$.

I appreciate any kind of help. Thank you for reading.

Comment: For $\varphi\left(n\right) < n^n$, I think you can prove the stronger claim that $\left|\varphi\left(n\right)\right| \leq \left(n-1\right)!$ by induction over $n$ using the recursive formula you mentioned (and using the triangle inequality).

Comment: Actually, better results seem to exist in print: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/009731659190033D

Comment: @darijgrinberg Triangle inequality of what metric? The article you posted is a bit advanced for me right now though it seems interesting. Thank you.

Comment: Triangle inequality for absolute values of integers :)

Comment: The second equation of Lemma 1.1 in Ziegler's article should give you a way to construct a family of posets whose Möbius function increases exponentially compared to their size. This should yield a proof for $\varphi\left(n\right) > n^2$.